# Boton contactar con el anunciante independiente en el resultado de una categoría

Tags: php, mysql

La pregunta es: ¿como hacer un botón de contacto independiente a cada anuncio?

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$pegar = "SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE idsubcategoria = '$cat'";    
$cad = mysql_query($pegar,$con) or die ( 'error al listar, $pegar' .mysql_errno());

while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($cad)){
//muestro los resultados dentro de un DIV


<div id="abc1">
<div id="popupContact1">
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<form action="" id="form6" name="form6" autocomplete="off" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend style="font-size: 16pt;"><b>Contactar con el anunciante</b></legend>
            <img id="close" src="/images/x.png" onclick ="div_hide1()" width="10" height="10">
            <?php if ($array["nombre"] != ""){ ?>
            <a href="#tel" style="color: #900;" onclick="hacer_click()"><b>Ver Teléfono pinche aquí</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div><b id="ver-nombre">Nombre anunciante: <em style="color:#CCFFFF;"><?php echo utf8_encode($array["nombre"]); ?></em></b></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (isset($array["telefono"]) && $array["telefono"] != ""){ ?>
            <div id="ver-telefono"><b>Teléfono: <a href="tel://<?php echo utf8_encode($array["telefono"]); ?>"   style="color:#006600;"><?php echo utf8_encode($array["telefono"]); ?></a></b></div><br>
            <?php } ?> 
            <label>Enviar mensaje al correo del anunciante</label><br>
            <label><strong>Tu email:</strong></label><br />
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" required autocomplete="off" /><br /><br />
            <label><strong>Tu nombre:</strong></label><br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" /><br /><br />
            <label><strong>Mensaje:</strong></label><br />
            <TEXTAREA ROWS=4 COLS=32 name="mensaje" class="inputs" id="texto" tabindex="2" style="width:280px;height:142px;" maxlength="600" minlength="10" required onpaste="return false" placeholder="Mensaje..."></TEXTAREA><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar">

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<!-- Display Popup Button -->

// dentro del div y del while coloco el botón contactar y el form
    <a onclick="contacto1()"><button id="submit1">Contactar</button></a>

    // Uno de los array, es decir, registro contiene el correo del anunciante

    }
    ?>
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$to = $array["email"];
$subject = 'Alguien está interesado en tu anuncio.';
$htmlContent = "
                <h2>Detalles de la solicitud de contacto</h2>
                <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
                <p><b>Nombre: </b>".$nombre."</p>
                <p><b>Mensaje: </b>".$mensaje."</p>
                <p><b>Anuncio: </b>".utf8_encode($array["titulo"])."</p>
                <p>Un saludo desde la administración</p>
            ";
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            // More headers
            $headers .= 'From: Expoanuncios.net ' . "\r\n";

@mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

}

?>
```

Lo que necesito es seleccionar el email de cada anuncio dentro de la categoría en cuestión
¿Cómo selecciono el email en concreto para cada anunciante en el listado de categorías?

He probado con foreach $array pero si éxito...

Gracias por todo, un saludo.

La funcion contacto1() es javascript, y solamente muestra el formulario de contacto para contactar

```
function contacto1() { document.getElementById('abc1').style.display = "block"; }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer: **[cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que cada anuncio tenga el email de contacto del anunciante (por ejemplo en el campo `email`) entonces puedes pasar ese valor como parámetro de la función `contacto1`.

Algo como

```
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($cad)){
    //muestro los resultados dentro de un DIV
    // dentro del div y del while coloco el botón contactar
    echo '<a onclick="contacto1(' . $array['email'] . ')">';
    echo '<button id="submit1">Contactar</button>';
    echo '</a>';
}
```

Evidentemente esto requeriría que la función cambiase para esperar un correo como parámetro en vez de usar un correo en duro como debes tenerlo ahora.

Comment: Lo entiendo, como es posible eso? es decir, en la función contacto1() pasarle el valor del email? Mil gracias por tu respuesta amigo.

Comment: en el código que pegué estoy pasando el email a la función de contacto. Si pones tu función contacto en tu pregunta, puedo decirte cómo editarla para usar el parámetro

Comment: LA función contacto1, solamente muestra el formulario POPUP de contacto.

Comment: function contacto1() {
document.getElementById('abc1').style.display = "block";
}

Comment: Añade eso a tu pregunta. Añade también el contenido del div abc1. ¿Contiene un formulario? ¿Ese formulario tiene un campo para correo del anunciante?

Comment: Editado... Como te digo, muestra el formulario, ese formulario no debe contener el correo del anunciante, puesto que debe estar oculto a los ojos de todo el mundo... si existe $_POST["enviar"] osea, envian el formulario... debe ir al destinatario en cuestión, NO al primero que quiera. Como $array["email"] está dentro de un while... debo sacarlo o no sé que hacer para poder enviar al destinatario de cada anuncio. Gracias

Comment: En ese caso, incluye el formulario en tu pregunta, y el código del backend en donde procesas lo enviado por éste para enviar el correo.

Comment: Hecho, editado el post